# jQuery is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to do a pop-up window that contains 10 images. The pop-up should be visible only when the user presses the button to select his image. I am trying to understand why when I pressed the button to see the pop-up JS raised an error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: showAvatarPopup is not defined
>       at HTMLInputElement.onclick ((index):420)

According to my understanding this error been since the object wasn't created but I couldn't understand why the object wasn't created. How to fix it?

```js
 var modal;
            window.onload = function() {
                // Get the modal
                modal = document.getElementById('registrationBox');
            }
    
            // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
            window.onclick = function(event) {
                if (event.target == modal) {
                    modal.style.display = "none";
                }
            }
    
            function validate_in() {
                var userName = window.loginForm.username.value;
                var password = window.loginForm.password.value;
    
                if ((userName.length < 4) || (password.length < 6))
                {
                    alert('user name must be at least 4 characters,\nand password must be at least 6 characters');
                    return false;
                }
    
                return true;
            }
    
            function validate_up() {
                var firstname = document.signup.FirstName.value;
                var lastname = document.signup.LastName.value;
                var username = document.signup.username.value;
                var email = document.signup.email.value;
                var password = document.signup.psw.value;
                var passwordrepeat = document.signup.psw-repeat.value;
                var bday = document.signup.bday.value;
                var img = document.signup.img.value;
    
    
                if ((userName.length < 4))
                {ְ
                    alert('user name must be at least 5 characters');
                    return false;
                }
                if ((password.equals(passwordrepeat)))
                {
                    alert('Passwords are not the same');
                    return false;
                }
                if ((password.equals(passwordrepeat)))
                {
                    alert('Passwords are not the same');
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
    
            function forgetPasswordButtonClicked() {
                var popup = document.getElementById("forgetPasswordPopup");
                popup.classList.toggle("show");
            }
    
            function passwordRecovery() {
                myWindow = window.open("https://127.0.0.1:5000/passwordRecoveryStepOne", "password recovery", "width=100, height=100,statusbar=0,menubar=0,toolbar=0");
               myWindow.resizeTo(700, 550);
                myWindow.focus();
    
            }
    
            function showAvatarPopup() {
                $('.hover_bkgr_fricc').show();
            }
    
            function closeAvatarPopup() {
                $('.hover_bkgr_fricc').hide();
            }
    
            function pictureChoose(pictureNumber) {
                $('#photoNumber')[0].value = pictureNumber;
                $('.hover_bkgr_fricc').hide();
            }
```

```css
 /* Full-width input fields */
            input[type=text], input[type=password],input[type=date],input[type=file],input[type=email] {
                width: 100%;
                padding: 15px;
                margin: 5px 0 22px 0;
                display: inline-block;
                border: none;
                background: #f1f1f1;
            }
    
            /* Add a background color when the inputs get focus */
            input[type=text]:focus, input[type=password]:focus,input[type=date]:focus,input[type=file]:focus,input[type=email]:focus {
                background-color: #ddd;
                outline: none;
            }
    
            /* Set a style for all buttons */
            button {
                background-color: #4CAF50;
                color: white;
                padding: 14px 20px;
                margin: 8px 0;
                border: none;
                cursor: pointer;
                width: 100%;
                opacity: 0.9;
            }
    
            button:hover {
                opacity: 1;
            }
    
            /* Extra styles for the cancel button */
            .cancelbtn {
                padding: 14px 20px;
                background-color: #f44336;
            }
    
            /* Float cancel and signup buttons and add an equal width */
            .cancelbtn, .signupbtn {
                float: left;
                width: 50%;
            }
    
            /* Add padding to container elements */
            .container {
                padding: 16px;
            }
    
            /* The Modal (background) */
            .modal {
                display: none;
                /* Hidden by default */
                position: fixed;
                /* Stay in place */
                z-index: 1;
                /* Sit on top */
                left: 0;
                top: 0;
                width: 100%;
                /* Full width */
                height: 100%;
                /* Full height */
                overflow: auto;
                /* Enable scroll if needed */
                background-color: #474e5d;
                padding-top: 50px;
            }
    
            /* Modal Content/Box */
            .modal-content {
                background-color: #fefefe;
                margin: 5% auto 15% auto;
                /* 5% from the top, 15% from the bottom and centered */
                border: 1px solid #888;
                width: 80%;
                /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
            }
    
            /* Style the horizontal ruler */
            hr {
                border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
                margin-bottom: 25px;
            }
    
            /* The Close Button (x) */
            .close {
                position: absolute;
                right: 35px;
                top: 15px;
                font-size: 40px;
                font-weight: bold;
                color: #f1f1f1;
            }
    
            .close:hover, .close:focus {
                color: #f44336;
                cursor: pointer;
            }
    
            /* Clear floats */
            .clearfix::after {
                content: "";
                clear: both;
                display: table;
            }
    
            /* Change styles for cancel button and signup button on extra small screens */
            @media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
                .cancelbtn, .signupbtn {
                    width: 100%;
                }
            }
    /*http://i66.tinypic.com/2nndag.jpg*/
    
            body {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                background: url(https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png);  /*http://i66.tinypic.com/2nndag.jpg*/
                background-size: cover;
                background-position: center;
                font-family: sans-serif;
            }
    
            .login-box {
                width: 320px;
                height: 420px;
                background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
                color: #fff;
                top: 50%;
                left: 50%;
                position: absolute;
                transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
                box-sizing: border-box;
                padding: 70px 30px;
            }
    
            .avatar {
                width: 100px;
                height: 100px;
                border-radius: 50%;
                position: absolute;
                top: -50px;
                left: calc(50% - 50px);
            }
    
            h1 {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0 0 20px;
                text-align: center;
                font-size: 22px;
            }
    
            .login-box p {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                font-weight: bold;
            }
    
            .login-box input {
                width: 100%;
                margin-bottom: 20px;
            }
    
            .login-box input[type="text"], input[type="password"] {
                border: none;
                border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
                background: transparent;
                outline: none;
                height: 40px;
                color: #fff;
                font-size: 16px;
            }
    
            .login-box input[type="submit"] {
                border: none;
                outline: none;
                height: 40px;
                background: #1c8adb;
                color: #fff;
                font-size: 18px;
                border-radius: 20px;
            }
    
            .login-box input[type="submit"]:hover {
                cursor: pointer;
                background: #39dc79;
                color: #000;
            }
    
            .login-box a {
                text-decoration: none;
                font-size: 14px;
                color: #fff;
            }
    
            .login-box a:hover {
                color: #39dc79;
            }
    
    
    .button {
                background-color: #f4511e;
                border: none;
                color: white;
                padding: 16px 32px;
                text-align: center;
                font-size: 16px;
                margin: 4px 2px;
                opacity: 0.6;
                transition: 0.3s;
                display: inline-block;
                text-decoration: none;
                cursor: pointer;
              }
    
              .button:hover {opacity: 1}
    
    
    
    
              /* Popup box BEGIN */
                .hover_bkgr_fricc{
                    cursor:pointer;
                    display:none;
                    height:100%;
                    position:fixed;
                    text-align:center;
                    top:0;
                    width:100%;
                    z-index:10000;
                }
                .hover_bkgr_fricc .helper{
                    display:inline-block;
                    height:100%;
                    vertical-align:middle;
                }
                .hover_bkgr_fricc > div {
                    background-color: #fff;
                    box-shadow: 10px 10px 60px #555;
                    display: inline-block;
                    height: auto;
                    max-width: 551px;
                    min-height: 100px;
                    vertical-align: middle;
                    width: 60%;
                    position: relative;
                    border-radius: 8px;
                    padding: 15px 5%;
                }
                .popupCloseButton {
                    background-color: #fff;
                    border: 3px solid #999;
                    border-radius: 50px;
                    cursor: pointer;
                    display: inline-block;
                    font-family: arial;
                    font-weight: bold;
                    position: absolute;
                    top: -20px;
                    right: -20px;
                    font-size: 25px;
                    line-height: 30px;
                    width: 30px;
                    height: 30px;
                    text-align: center;
                }
                /*
                ul {
                    list-style: none; /* Remove list bullets */
                    padding: 350;
                    margin: 80;
                    }
                */
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<div class="login-box">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png " class="avatar">  /*http://i64.tinypic.com/n1w8ip.jpg */
        <h1>Login Here</h1>
        <form action="" class="form" method="post" name="loginForm" onsubmit="return validate_in();">
            <p>Username</p>
            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter Username" required>
            <p>Password</p>
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter Password" required>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login">
            <a href="#" onclick="passwordRecovery();">Forget Password</a>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('registrationBox').style.display='block'">Sign Up</a>
        </form>
    </div>
    
    <div id="registrationBox" class="modal">
        <span onclick="document.getElementById('registrationBox').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
        <form class="modal-content" method="post" action="/register" name="signup" enctype="multipart/form-data>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="container-fluid" style = "min-height:100% width:80%">

              {% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
              {% if messages %}
                <ul class=flashes>
                {% for message in messages %}
                  <li>{{ message }}</li>
                {% endfor %}
                </ul>
              {% endif %}
            {% endwith %}


            </div>
            <h1>Sign Up to YH ch</h1>
            <hr>

            <label for="FirstName"><b>First name</b></label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your first name" name="FirstName" required>

            <label for="LastName"><b>Last name</b></label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your last name" name="LastName" required>

            <label for="username"><b>Username</b></label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter username" name="username" required>

            <label for="email"><b>Email</b></label>
            <input type="email" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" required>

            <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>

            <label for="psw-repeat"><b>Repeat Password</b></label>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Repeat Password" name="psw-repeat" required>

            <label for="Birthday"><b>Birthday:</b></label>
            <input type="date" name="bday" required>

            <input type="radio" name="photoSelection" value="select" onclick="showAvatarPopup();"/> Select avator
            <br/>
            <input type="radio" name="photoSelection" value="upload" onclick="$('#photoUpload').show();"/> Upload my own
            photo
            <label for="photoUpload"><b>Select avatar image:</b></label>
            <input type="file" name="photoUpload" id="photoUpload" accept="image/*" style="display: none;"/>

            <div class="hover_bkgr_fricc">
                <span class="helper"></span>
                <div>
                    <div class="popupCloseButton" onclick="closeAvatarPopup();">X</div>

                    <input type="hidden" name="photoNumber" id="photoNumber"/>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png" width="100"
                                     height="100" onclick="pictureChoose(1);"/></td>
                            <td><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png"
                                     width="100" height="100" onclick="pictureChoose(2);"/></td>
                            <td><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png" width="100"
                                     height="100" onclick="pictureChoose(3);"/></td>
                            <td><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTbtWTxrQPNCQm4hmm0yvs06aGPiboCnpmOfFp-FexbvslTNG5h" width="100"
                                     height="100" onclick="pictureChoose(4);"/></td>
                            <td><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRNDbeyfZVxA7f9TclbDU6-MCkh60XWWF3rpF0OXvXAVshqt78h" width="100"
                                     height="100" onclick="pictureChoose(5);"/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTL9D0dsfs2LDamDqkrMy3ckK2zVYLiC44ztxS1TI6QgPJIrvVD" width="100"
                                     height="100" onclick="pictureChoose(6);"/></td>
                            <td><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSU8cqkaylj5eyFTzGTpf6LBFJAOOvpV249ASkChohmAnILcto-vQ" width="100"
                                     height="100" onclick="pictureChoose(7);"/></td>
                            <td><img src="https://kiteloft.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/728x/17f82f742ffe127f42dca9de82fb58b1/d/a/davedes2_1.jpg" width="100"
                                     height="100" onclick="pictureChoose(8);"/></td>
                            <td><img src="https://www.dailydot.com/wp-content/uploads/617/e8/12717ea046003e9db9972177e7001e0b.jpg" width="100"
                                     height="100" onclick="pictureChoose(9);"/></td>
                            <td><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png" width="100"
                                     height="100" onclick="pictureChoose(10);"/></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>


                </div>
            </div>


            <p>By creating an account you agree to our <a href="#" style="color:dodgerblue">Terms & Privacy</a>.</p>

            <div class="clearfix">
                <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('registrationBox').style.display='none'"
                        class="cancelbtn">Cancel
                </button>
                <button type="submit" class="signupbtn" onclick="return validate_up()">Sign Up</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

The specific function problem is

```
function showAvatarPopup() {

        $('.hover_bkgr_fricc').show();
    }

    function closeAvatarPopup() {
        $('.hover_bkgr_fricc').hide();
    }

    function pictureChoose(pictureNumber) {
        $('#photoNumber')[0].value = pictureNumber;
        $('.hover_bkgr_fricc').hide();
    }
```

It should be open when I press this

```
<input type="radio" name="photoSelection" value="select" onclick="showAvatarPopup();"/> Select avator
```

Comment: You won't get that error with the code as shown, `showAvatarPopup` is clearly global (as it needs to be to be referenced from an old-style attribute handler like that). Please update your question Please update your question with a [mcve] (emphasis on each of those, including "minimal") demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)).

Comment: why you are using very old jquery ?!! try using a newer version of it

Comment: Use event listeners, not `onclick` attributes.